# Flex ModuleManager unload module

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I use ModuleManager load a module, like this Class:

```
 public class LoadModule
    {
        private static var info:IModuleInfo;
        private static var display:IVisualElement;
        private static var downloadBar:ProgressBar;
        private static var parent:Group;


        public function LoadModule()
        {

        }
        //load module
        public static function load(url:String, parent:Group, bar:Boolean = true):void {
            LoadModule.parent = parent;
            info = ModuleManager.getModule(url);
            info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, readyHandler);
            info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.SETUP, setupHandler);
            info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
            info.load(null, null, null, parent.moduleFactory);

        }

        //add display object
        private static function readyHandler(event:ModuleEvent):void {
            LoadModule.display = event.currentTarget.factory.create() as IVisualElement;
            parent.addElement(LoadModule.display);
        }

        private static function setupHandler(event:ModuleEvent):void {

        }
        //unload module
        public static function unload():void {
            if (LoadModule.info != null) {
                LoadModule.info.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.UNLOAD, unloadHandler);
                LoadModule.info.unload();
                if (parent.getElementIndex(LoadModule.display) != -1) {
                    parent.removeAllElements();
                    LoadModule.display = null;
                }
            }
        }

        private static function unloadHandler(event:ModuleEvent):void {
            LoadModule.info.removeEventListener(ModuleEvent.UNLOAD,unloadHandler);
            trace("unloadModue");
        }
        //
        private static function progresshandler(event:ModuleEvent):void {
            downloadBar.label = "haved" + Math.round((event.bytesLoaded /event.bytesTotal) * 100) + "%";
        }

        private static function errorHandler(event:ModuleEvent):void {
            throw Error(event.errorText);
        }

        public static function setDownloadbar(downloadBar:ProgressBar):void {
            LoadModule.downloadBar = downloadBar;
        }
    }
```

Then i load a module and unload a module:

```
 LoadModule.unload(); // 1
   LodModule.load('..one.swf', parent);
   LoadModule.unload(); //2
   LodModule.load('...one.swf', parent);
```

In theory, It's only one module in my application, and I use "PopUpManager" pop a box, it shoud be one box. But, in fact, It's pop tow box. 
I use Flash builder debug this code, and It does not notice me  unloade swf..
I guess, It has tow module in appliction.
So, I need help. How to unload module in ModuleManager. I wish one module in application , not tow.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, it sounds like you are having trouble unloading your module.  There's a great [Adobe resource](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2009/08/what_we_know_about_unloading_m.html) that can help you solve these issues.  A few considerations:

> "If you have a module that does not unload, the steps to diagnose the problem are:
>   1)  Make sure the module is being loaded into a child applicationDomain (use default parameters for the load() method in most cases)
>   2)  Use the profiler to make sure there are no references to objects in the module."

If you reference any objects in the module, the module will not unload.  You will want to check that the following areas make no reference to the module in question:

1. Styles
2. Resources
3. ExternalInterface.addCallback functions
4. Timers and Timer mechanisms
5. Listeners
6. Focus
7. Remote Objects
8. Loaded images

Comment: This is a definite possibility, but I'd also like to add that the code you currently have is riddled with potential problems since you're using static variables and aren't removing the event listeners.

Comment: Hi,I am a beginner. The code is not good, and my mother tongue is Chinese. So Thank you all for answering.